# I am having issue installing numpy in windows

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I had Python 3.9.0 32 bit installed in my windows system and successfully installed numpy using the command: `pip install numpy` in the command Prompt.

I then had to switch to Python 3.9.0 64 bit and I was unable to use numpy from here on so I tried to install it again but I got the following error;

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1
```

When I used the command `pip uninstall numpy`, I get the following message:

```
WARNING: Skipping numpy as it is not installed*
```

I already uninstalled Python 3.9.0 64 Bit and reinstalled it again and it still did not work.
I even used the command `pip install -U pip setuptools` and nothing.

I will appreciate if anyone can help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you tried `pip3 install numpy` or `pip install numpy` after installing python 64bit?

Comment: Yes, I tried pip3 install numpy and pip install numpy. I get the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

i think Windows has both Python versions mixed up, or there are traces of both 32 bit and 64 bit, have a look at the `PATH` environment variables, and other variables relating to Python are using the right file path.

If this does not resolve the issue remove both versions of Python and use a CCleaner to remove any traces of Python from your computer, and check what you are removing with CCleaner, and then install Python 32 bit version again, and then numpy.